# How to customize toolbar in Team Explorer Source Control Explorer sub-window?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

I have Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012 installed, which lets me then access files stored on my employer's TFS server.  I mainly use it to check out files, modify them in a non-VS tool, then upload the changed versions to TFS.  In the Team Explorer window, there's a Source Control Explorer window/tab that has its own toolbar separate from the main Team Explorer window's toolbar:

[image: screenshot showing toolbar in question]

I want to customize this toolbar, to add a button.  But I can't find anything that matches it under TOOLS-> Customize-> Commands-> Toolbar.  Googling gets me unrelated results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't.  That window is just a helpful manager - so you have open, synchronize, create folder, add file, delete, etc - which is what the window is for.  What would you want to add there?

Comment: I'd like to add a button that gets changeset 1 of the selected item (to remove my local copy of the item).

Comment: Not sure i understood - you can already delete selected items - and unless it's a folder, when you delete an item it goes straight to recycle bin

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using local workspaces. So if I delete the file or folder TFS tracks that as a change. The get changeset 1 trick is the only method I've find to remove the local copy without TFS seeing it as a deletion.

Comment: So you want to delete an item but not inform the TFS when you commit/sync? Why? TFS is meant to be used for tracking changes (like subversion and the like) - that's the all point of TFS

Comment: I'm using multiple branches with a large code base. When I'm no longer working on a particular branch there is no need to keep a copy of the branch on my computer. So I just want to remove the local copy, like an unget.